# C# DateTime to Excel Time

Tags: c#, .net, excel

How can I create a column that displays only the time and not the date and time in Excel?\

This is what is displayed in Excel

```
13.09.2022  12:24:16
```

Setting the NumberFormat with "hh:mm:ss" is not working

```
List<DateTime> time = new List<DateTime>();

worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
worksheet.Range[$"$A$1:$A{time.Count}"].Value = excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(time.ToArray());
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the format of the target range before value is set? E.g. as `worksheet.Range[$"$A$1:$A{time.Count}"].NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss;@"`. Check Excel [formats](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309#:~:text=On%20the%20Home%20tab%2C%20in,that%20you%20want%20to%20use.).

Comment: The format is correct now, but the cell still shows the date and time. Only when I select the cell with the mouse, only the time is displayed. Is it possible to insert only the time without the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by converting `DateTime` to a `double` with a range from 0 to 1

```
time = hour / 24.0 + minute / 24.0 / 60.0 + second / 24.0 / 60.0 / 60.0
```